# Unable to configure proxy for ASP.NET application to be viewed on Apache website

Tags: asp.net, .net, apache, proxy, virtualhost

I am doing a project where a running ASP.NET application (ran by dotnet core) is to be portrayed on a website via apache. I am having trouble with the proxy and get some interesting log errors I can't understand.

```
[Fri Jan 06 10:54:01.049808 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 17756:tid 3045061632] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 5.150.205.190:61781] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server localhost:7199, referer: http://www.website.me/ 
[Fri Jan 06 10:54:01.050039 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 17756:tid 3045061632] [client 5.150.205.190:61781] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /favicon.ico, referer: http://www.website.me/
```

The VirtualHost is kept simple

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.website.me
    ServerAlias www.website.me
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:7199/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:7199/"
</VirtualHost>
```

I've consulted with ChatGPT, referring me vaguely to possible network issues between the application and apache. But since both are running I don't see the issue with simply pointing to the localhost view. I can view it locally in browser. **Why can't I point to it?**

Comment: make sure the kestrel is running your app. So that apache can make the connection. The `dotnet yourapp.dll` will run your app on kestrel.